# Arrangement of $12$ people in a row such that neither of $2$ particular persons sit on either of $2$ ends of the row

Tags: combinatorics

> If $12$ persons are arranged in a row such that neither of two particular persons can sit on either end of the row, is

My attempt:

Total ways $=$ Sitting $12$ persons in a row $-$ Sitting $2$ particular persons $2$ ends of the row

$$=12!-2!\cdot 10!$$

But it seems that this answer is wrong.

Can anyone please explain to me the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn’t understand what you wrote. Are you saying that: there are $12$ people and there are $2$ particular people that can’t sit at each end of the row?

Comment: I have edited my question.please find it. Thanks

Comment: your answer includes arrangements in which one of the two special people is at an end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only removed from your count where *both* of your people sit at the ends and have neglected to remove where only *one* of your people sit at the ends but not the other.

Rather than thinking in terms of the perspective of the seats... we can think with respect to the *people* instead and approach with rule of product like usual.

- Pick which seat the younger of the two special people sit (*noting it cannot be either end*):  10 choices
- Pick which seat the older of the two special people sit (*noting it cannot be either end or where the first person sat*): 9 choices
- Pick which seat the youngest of the remaining people sit (*noting it cannot be where either of the first two people sat but now may include the ends*): 10 choices
- Pick which seat the next youngest of the remaining people sit (*similar restrictions*): 9 choices
- Continue in this fashion seating each of the rest of the people in sequence

You will find then that there are $10\cdot 9\cdot 10!$ total arrangements.

Answer (score 3):

Excluding the seats at each end, there are ten seats that these two people can be placed in, with $T_{9}= \frac{9(9+1)}{2}=45$ choices for this.

They can do this in either order, so we double the result.

The remaining ten seats can be filled in $10!$ ways with the other ten people.

This gives a total of $10!×45×2=10!×90$ arrangements meeting the conditions you have.

Answer (score 3):

What the OP subtracted from $12!$ is the number of arrangements in which *both* ends are occupied by the two particular people, but the problem wants us to eliminate the arrangements in which *either* end is occupied by one of them. This is more easily counted directly, by first seating the two particular people in the interior $10$ seats, which can be done in $10\cdot9$ ways, then seating the remaining $10$ people willy nilly, which can be done in $10!$ ways, for a total of

$$10\cdot9\cdot10!$$

arrangements.

Comment: Wow, three essentially identical answers within twelve seconds of one another!

Comment: Mine was 4 mins earlier than them. However, OP should accept the answer which is most helpful *to him* imo

Comment: @AdamRubinson, yes, your answer did a nice job of explaining what the OP had neglected to exclude.

Comment: Stop- you’re making me blush

Answer (score 2):

$12! - (2! . 10!)$ is the number of ways $12$ people can be arranged, excluding the cases where person A and person B are both at the ends *at the same time*.

You haven’t excluded the cases where person $A$ is at one end and person $B$ *isn’t* at the other end, and same with $A <-> B$

Answer (score 1):

The $10$ normal persons can be seated in $10!$ ways. There are $9$ slots in between them for the  special persons. When the first special person is seated there are $10$ slots for the second special person. Therefore there are
$$10!\cdot  9\cdot 10=326\,592\,000$$
admissible seatings for the $12$ persons.